# Jasperreport Null Pointer on weblogic 11g

Tags: struts2, weblogic

I've deployed my struts2 application which uses jasperreports plugin. When deploying
in Glassfish3 and Tomcat, the reports working fine. But when I deploy to Weblogic 11g
the following NPE is given.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.sendError(ServletResponseImpl.java:645)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.sendError(Dispatcher.java:819)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:519)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3592)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2202)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2108)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1432)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue?
I'm using struts 2.2.3 and struts2-jasper-reports plugin 2.2.3.